# AngularJS call to Restful Webservice in java returning an error

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

I have a restful webservice that returns a list of users .I am calling the method using AngularJS
My Restful Webservice:

```
package webservice;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import model.ProjectManager;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dto.Users;
@Path("/WebService")
public class UsersService {
@GET
@Path("/GetUsers")
@Produces("application/json")
public String user()
{
  String users = null;
  try 
  {
    ArrayList<Users> usersList = null;
    ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
    usersList = projectManager.GetUsers();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(usersList));
    users = gson.toJson(usersList);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Exception Error"); //Console 
  }
   return users;
 }
}
```

and the output is:

```
[{"userId":1,"userName":"sdsouza"},{"userId":3,"userName":"administrator"}]
```

The http url is yielding the results just fine.

My controllers.js in Angular Js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get( 
'http://localhost:8081/TestDataRestful/REST/WebService/GetUsers'
).success(function(data) {          
    $scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.users = data;
     });
      })
   .error(function(data) {
    $scope.message="error";
    });
  }])
```

When I run the html page,I see that the call is getting made.The console prints out the result but the html page prints out the error message and there is no sight of the users.I am a noob.I would be grateful if anyone can spot the error.I have been battling with it for quite some time.Thanks in advance.

```
 <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
 <ion-content class="padding">
 <div class="list card">
 <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
 <div class="item item-body">
 {{message}}
 </div>
 <div class="item item-body" ng-repeat="user in users">
 {{user}}
 </div>
 </div>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Comment: First of all remove the $scope.apply ,$http do this for you in the backend.You dont need to apply digest cycle manually.
Just simple $scope.users=data

Comment: Check also in the Chrome console or firebug if you are getting any error. Maybe it can be something related with the mime-type of the response

Comment: @squiroid: Still the same error

Comment: Is console.log(data); prints anything in success function?

Comment: Tried that too.The control doesn't go to the success block at all.Thanks for trying to help though.I appreciate it

Comment: Have you checked the mime type of the response? it should be application/json, if not, at least sometimes, it will detect the mismatching mime type as an error (it has happened to me lots of times..)

Comment: @Eylen:It is application/json.Thanks for trying to help though.I appreciate it

Comment: and the status code is 200?

Comment: It doesn't give me any status code.Just not returning the data

Comment: I mean in the network tab of the chrome console or firebug

Comment: I checked in chrome console.No messages.The web service is called.

Answer (score 0):

It was not the code.I needed to add CORS filter in the webapp's web.xml file.
If you are using Tomcat 7 and above,there is no need to add cors jars,just include the filters in the xml file.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
<param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
<param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-  
Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
<param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-
Credentials</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
<param-value>10</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Special thanks to Mike's article.I used ionic.So I could skip the first configuration of including the httpProvider in the js file.

http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.5.htm